# Codeigniter consecutive queries creates undefined indexes

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I've been having a problem with consecutive queries. I don't know if CodeIgniter has something to do with it. Can anyone enlighten me if what's going on?

Given:
`$Attendees` is an Array of employee numbers.
`$data` is an Array from a $_POST
`$data ['quads'.trim($attendees[$i])]` - I am trying to attain to get the POST data with an index of `quads1234567` wherein the numbers is the employee number.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($attendees)-1; $i++){

        $data_update = array(
            'QD'.$data['quads'.trim($attendees[$i])][0].'RTE' => 3 ,
            'FTRNNG'  => 'N' ,
        );

        $this->db->where('TRNSRS', $data['series']); 
        $this->db->where('EMPNUM', trim($attendees[$i])); 
        $this->db->update('EmployeeSmartsDB', $data_update); 

        $data = array(
           'YRSEM'  => '201301' ,
           'EMPNUM' => trim($attendees[$i]) ,
           'UNTCDE' => $data['unitcode'] ,
           'TRNTYP' => $data['training_type'],
           'TRNSRS' => $data['series'] ,
           'SKLCDE' => $data['skillcde'] ,
           'ACTDTE' => '20130912' ,
           'ACTTME' => '1534' ,
           'EMPRTE' => $data['quads'.trim($attendees[$i])][1],
           'QUDRNT' => $data['quads'.trim($attendees[$i])][0],
           'RMARKS' => $data['remarks'.trim($attendees[$i])],
        );

        $this->db->insert('EmployeeLedgerDB', $data); 

    }
```

Now, the case is that when I comment out the insert query the whole thing executes flawlessly but once I include the insert query, the index of `$data ['quads'.trim($attendees[$i])]` is not defined and also the `$data['series']` index is also not defined.

All of the errors happens in the update query and not in the insert query. I even tried echoing the values and they disappear when the insert query is uncommented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps:

```
$insertData   = array(              #change the name of the array as $data you said is already assiged 
   'YRSEM'  => '201301' ,
   'EMPNUM' => trim($attendees[$i]) ,
   'UNTCDE' => $data['unitcode'] ,
   'TRNTYP' => $data['training_type'],
   'TRNSRS' => $data['series'] ,
   'SKLCDE' => $data['skillcde'] ,
   'ACTDTE' => '20130912' ,
   'ACTTME' => '1534' ,
   'EMPRTE' => $data['quads'.trim($attendees[$i])][1],
   'QUDRNT' => $data['quads'.trim($attendees[$i])][0],
   'RMARKS' => $data['remarks'.trim($attendees[$i])],
);

$this->db->insert_batch('EmployeeLedgerDB', $insertData);
```

Comment: You can also use the `insert_batch` function of `CI`.

Comment: Yes, yes! you're Right! Thank you! @Nilo. That was the answer. I was about to type my answer but you already posted it. Thank you!